# How to connect another raspberry pi as an device to Greengrass group and communicate with each other?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am new to AWS-IoT, I would like to understand how greengrass works,

1. I would like to communicate 2 raspberry pi's locally using amazon greengrass. So does both the raspberry pi needs green grass core installed ?
2. Or, is it enough that we install green grass core software in one raspberry pi and add another raspberry pi as a device in AWS greengrass IoT console.

3.if it is possible, how does the communication works locally between two raspberry pi's.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. only one needs to be a greengrass "core" device.
2. Yes!
3. Local communication (MQTT) is automatic (provided that an Ethernet/WiFi connection is established) and works through publish/subscribe pattern (you need to communicate with the cloud at least once for the automatic configuration process to take place after you configured greengrass core, thing, group, policy ecc. on AWS site)